# Use Android hardware DSP to filter sensor data

Tags: android, fft, accelerometer, sensors, lowpass-filter

I would like to **low pass filter** and **FFT** my data stream from the Accelerometer can this be done in hardware?.[image: FFT]

Comment: why do you want to do this? There are lot of calucations done at sensor HAL level. So you may have to reinvent wheel if you do it at driver level. Thou this is perfectly possible. Or you could achieve this at higher layers without any trouble.

Comment: So I want to filter out a known 60Hz oscillation, the device is sitting on a truck that has a vibrator (off center motor running at 60 or 75Hz)

Comment: @AnthonyKeane, you could just soft mount the device in those circumstances. That would do your filtering at the mechanical level rather than in software. The problem with filtering in software is that you're dependent on the accelerometer having the dynamic range to properly sense the vibration so that you can properly filter it, otherwise you could be left with some residual problems after the filter (harmonics, problem with the filter's length, it's Q, etc). I'm not sure that your average consumer grade android device has accelerometers with high dynamic range.